# Is this correct for showing a matrix representation of the $D_2$ group?

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

First, let’s consider that we have a line segment on $\mathbb{R}$. By the definition of symmetry, we have  $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is symmetric if $d(f(a),f(b))=d(a,b)$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then the only symmetries possible in $\mathbb{R}$ would be the identity and the reflection about the center, which in our segments case would be $\frac {(b-a)} 2$.

Therefore the two possible linear transformations would be represented by the following matrices:

$P_0 =\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $U_0 =  \begin{bmatrix} -1&0\\0&-1 \end{bmatrix}$

Now consider the line segment on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The only symmetries possible would be rotation and reflection.

Generally on a plane, the dihedral group $D_n$ is generated via rotations $2k/n$ and reflections $2k/n$ where $k = 0,1,2,…,n-1$.

Since this is the dihedral group $D_2$ we can only have $0$ ,  , $0$ and .

Therefore, we have the symmetries that flip the plane around the line that contains the line segment, we get the symmetry that flips the plane around the perpendicular bisector and we get that planes complement and the identity matrix.

This leaves us with four transformations:

$P_0=  \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$  $P_\pi=  \begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$   $U_0 = \begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$   $U_\pi=  \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$

Therefore the symmetry group of a line segment in $\mathbb{R}^1$ has order $2$ and the symmetry group of a line segment in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has order $4$.

Comment: I tried my best to edit this, now you can check whether my edit is correct or not. Make necessary changes ,if required.

Comment: Why do you draw distinction between $P_\pi$ and $U_0$? They are equal in your defintions above

Comment: Perhaps 

$$\left(
\begin{array}
\\
&-1 & 0 \\
&0  &-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: oh yes thats what i meant, both to be negative. Do these matrices represent what im trying to show or do you think im messing something up?